# Vim open file after :sh

Tags: vim

I would like to be able to go back to my terminal session while editing in vim (using `:sh`), cd into some other directory, and then open another file but in the same vim session I was in before. i.e. if i 'exit' in the terminal, I would like to go back to vim such that `:ls` shows both buffers.

Currently, if I `:sh`, `vim newfile`, I go into vim but `:ls` only shows the newfile.

Is there are way to add the new file to the previous session instead of starting a new one?

(Note: I'm not too familiar with vim terminology. By "session" I mean the instance of vim which has my previous buffers).

Comment: This begs the question: why? You can open new files from within Vim with `:e` and friends.

Comment: I just thought it would be nice to be able to do so. I don't find :e convenient even with tab completion as you have to stay going through each file one at a time. The shell at least allows me to list files/dirs. So instead I tend to use Nerdtree. But, when I have to open files which are nested in one too many sub-dirs, I run out of room in Nerdtree's side panel (so I open it full screen and open the file in a new tab - then I end up with too many tabs). The more ways I know how to do something the better because I can add up the pros cons and decide what's best for me in a given situation.

Comment: `:set wildmode=list:longest` to the rescue! Vim can do this. See `:h 'wildmode'`.

Comment: And `:set wildignorecase` and `:set wildmenu` ;-)

Comment: Awesome... I did not know about these options. I have not read a lot about them, just trying them out right now and wildmode=list:longest is so going in my .vimrc. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to go back to the shell to open other files: `:edit`, `:split`, `:vsplit`, `:tabedit` all allow you to edit files from anywhere on your disk (and with tab-completion):

```
:sp ../../path/to/file
```

You can play with the `wildmenu`, `wildmode` and `wildignorecase` options to make it even better.

You can also use the built-in Netrw plugin to navigate through your filesystem with a slightly more comfortable "graphical" explorer (see `:help netrw`):

```
:Ex
:Tex /path/to/
```

Also, `:shell` opens a *new* shell which most likely won't have much knowledge about your initial Vim session and thus won't be able to talk with it.

Comment: You make a good point at the end romainl. So, there is no way to do this then? If that's the case, I shall go ahead and accept your answer. Btw, I never used/looked into Netrw, but I do use Nerdtree, which I suppose is similar. True, it is an alternative, but I would still like to know whether I can do what I originally had in mind.

Comment: There's probably a way to do what you want (maybe with ingo's suggestion) but I can imagine it being both convoluted, verbose and fragile. And not worth the hassle in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, I accept that my fancy is not supported :P I just thought that I wouldn't be surprised if vim had a way to do something like this and it was probably buried deep in the documentation. So fine, this is not supported and there are ways around it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

When you go into a subshell with `:sh` and then invoke Vim, that'll be a brand new instance. What you can do instead is launch the original Vim with *client-server communication*:

```
$ vim --servername main
```

Unfortunately, when you go into a subshell with `:sh`, the original Vim is suspended, and you cannot communicate with it. You have to spawn another shell, e.g. in another terminal or *screen* split. If you now want to edit another file in the original Vim, use Vim's *client-server communication* to open it there:

```
$ vim --servername main --remove newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and suggestion. Unfortunately, this does not work for me... I am guessing because I have somehow managed to compile vim with very little extra features. `vim --version | grep server` gives me `-clientserver`, so I suppose that's why I can't do this. I intend to take a better look at compiling vim with more features after formatting / dedicate some time. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `:tabedit filename` than `gt` tp move move though tabs.

also <kbd>cntl</kbd> +<kbd>z</kbd> puts vim in te background and you can use your shell as normal. to get vim back. use the command `fg`

Comment: I am aware of some ways of opening new files while in vim. I would like to :sh and then open a file in my "old" vim session. If there's a way to do so using C^Z instead of :sh, that would be good to know too.